# Fancybox Automatic popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I downloaded Fancybox from net and am working on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'contact.php',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }
</style>
```

```
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="contact.php">Subscribe</a>
```

It's working well when you click the link.
But now i need it to automatically pop-up when someone logs into the homepage.
Can anyone help with the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fancybox does not directly support a way to automatically launch. The work around I was able to get working is creating a hidden anchor tag and triggering it's onclick event. Make sure your call to trigger the onclick event is included after the jquery and fancybox js files are included. The code I used is as follows:

This sample script is embedded directly in the html, but it could also be included in a js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

**Border Color**

Personally I do it from fancybox's css file, you should look for

> #fancybox-content

and

> .fancybox-outer

and change it's background-color or border color as per your demand.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: How is it possible to make the border color change, if you have any idea ??
threadless.com . Check this and see the subscription form at the homepage in colorbox.

Comment: your welcome and if you think that it solves your problem then please like my answer.thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code is working well. I have tested it myself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox({
                        'width': '40%',
                        'height': '40%',
                        'autoScale': true,
                        'transitionIn': 'fade',
                        'transitionOut': 'fade',
                        'type': 'iframe',
                        'href': 'http://www.example.com'
                    });
 });
```

N.B: I have tested it with version 2.1.4 
You might also try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             $("#fancybox-manual-a").trigger('click');
            });
```

there is an anchor tag with id `fancybox-manual-a`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.fancybox.open('#id');
    });
</script>
```